# In c++, is stream.clear() necessary after a failure has occurred?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have the following code:

```
string promptPlayerForFile(ifstream &infile, string prompt) {
    while (true) {
        string filename;
        cout << prompt;
        getline(cin, filename);
        infile.open(filename.c_str());
        if (!infile.fail()) return filename;
        infile.clear();
        cout << "Unable to open that file. Try again." << endl;
    }
}
```

The function works as expected: you enter file names until you give a correct one, in which case it associates a stream with the file and returns the filename string.

I then tried commenting out the line `infile.clear()` to see what happens. (I read that it needs to be included after a failure has occurred in order to reset the relevant bits of the stream.)

However, after commenting this out, the function behaves as before. If I first give a wrong filename and then a correct one it works, so somehow the failure bits get reset even without that line. Is then `infile.clear()` necessary and what are its appropriate uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C++11 or higher, you don't need to call `infile.clear();`. If `open()` is successful, then `clear()` is called.

If you are using a pre-C++11 compiler, it is necessary to call `infile.clear()`. The language does not guarantee that the failbit(s) are cleared when `open()` is successful.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open for details about the call to `clear()`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good reference for these changes? I couldn't find anything here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

Comment: @titiree, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open contains the details.

Answer (score 0):

the `infile.clear()` is relevant if and only if you want to continue to interact with the stream (e.g. read from it). If your program ends anyway, you dont't have to clear the error flags.