# Using getline() when my line is split into two lines, C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, getline, istringstream

I am reading from a file, specifically BLS data in text files. Some of the metro names are long and so the data for that city extends to the next line.
A snippet from the file:

```
999 26380 Houma-Thibodaux, LA  42   42   0   0  0   0   94
288 26420 Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land,
  TX              4424    3046       4       0    1374      34     100
170 26580 Huntington-Ashland, WV-KY-OH  7   1   0   6   0    0     85
```

I need to save the ints after the state into vectors, so first am placing them into the string variables "total, one,..., per." I omitted the vectors I am placing them in for brevity.
When the first two ints, the city, state, and next seven ints are on the same line (as they are for Houma and Huntington) my program works fine.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream BLS;
    vector <string> cities = {"Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land"};
    string city, state, total, one, two, three, five, struc, per, temp;
    BLS.open("trial.txt");
    if (BLS.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while(getline(BLS, line)) {
            istringstream sin(line);                 
            getline(sin, temp, ' ');
            getline(sin, temp, ' ');
            getline(sin, city, ','); 
            for (int i = 0; i < (int) cities.size(); i++) {
                if (city == cities[i]) {     
                    if (getline(sin, line) ) {
                        istringstream in(line);
                        in >> state >> total >> one >> two >> three >> five >> struc >> per;
                    }
                    else {
                        sin.ignore();
                        getline(sin, line);
                        istringstream in(line);
                        in >> state >> total >> one >> two >> three >> five >> struc >> per;
                    }
                    cout << " " << city << " " << state << " " << total << " " << five << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As with Houston, the getline in the "if" statement is empty, so "else" executes. But I would expect sin.ignore() and getline(sin, line) again to then read the following line:

```
TX    4424    3046    4   0   1374   34   100
```

but it never does. getline(sin, line) seems to continue to read the empty line.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When `getline` fails, it sets `failbit` on the stream. As long as this bit is set, every subsequent call would fail immediately before doing any work. Use [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to clear the bit.

Comment: [In c++, is stream.clear() necessary after a failure has occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375226/in-c-is-stream-clear-necessary-after-a-failure-has-occurred)

Comment: If I put BLS.clear() or sin.clear() or line.clear() in the "else" statement I get the same failure

Comment: Is there a guarantee that "city, state" contains exactly one comma, and that that comma separates the city and state? Or, to put it another way, can a city name contain a comma?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the BLS website where this particular data file is described?

Comment: For the cities I need, yes. https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3u201501.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Don't use `getline`

If the data are not structured cleanly into lines, then don't use `std::getline`. At least, that is, not in this case.

This solution uses a struct named `BLS_Table_3u` to contain the information from one record. It requires that the `city` field does not contain any commas, and also that each `city` is followed by a comma, and then the `state`. A scan of the data file on the BLS website confirms that these are valid assumptions.

```cpp
struct BLS_Table_3u
{
    // Copy this struct into your own program.
    // Source: https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3u201501.txt
    int csa;
    int cbsa;
    std::string name;
    int total; 
    int units_1; 
    int units_2;
    int units_3_and_4;
    int units_5_or_more;
    int n_structures_with_5_units_or_more;
    int monthly_coverage_percent;

    // Stream operators follow ... copy them too!
};
```

The struct defines `operator<<` and `operator>>` to handle I/O. `operator>>` reads one record from the data file, and stores the data it a `BLS_Table_3u` struct. Similarly, `operator<<` writes the record stored in a `BLS_Table_3u` struct.

First, of course, you must open the file.

```cpp
    std::string file_name{ "BLS_Table_3u.txt" };
    std::ifstream ist(file_name);
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error - Could not open data file.\n\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

With the file successfully opened, you can read a record into a `BLS_Table_3u` struct like this. If you have reached the end-of-file, the read attempt will fail.

```cpp
    BLS_Table_3u bls;  // Variable `bls` holds the data from one record.
    if (ist >> bls)
    { 
        // Extraction was successful. Process the data stored in `bls`.
    }
    else
    {
        // End-of-file: All the records have been read.
    }
```

More often than not, you will want to read the records in a loop. The test in the while-loop below is analogous to the test in the foregoing if-statement. The loop ends when you hit end-of-file.

```cpp
    BLS_Table_3u bls;
    while (ist >> bls)
    {
        // After reading a record, you can access its fields 
        // using things like `bls.name` and `bls.total`.
        // For example:
        // 
        //     if (bls.total > 1000) 
        //     {
        //          std::cout << bls.name << " has " 
        //              << bls.total << " units.\n";
        //     }
        // 
        // You can refer to the entire record using `bls` by itself, 
        // which is done below.

        std::cout << bls;  // Write a record to `std::cout`.
    }
    // Loop ends when you hit eof.
```

When an error is detected by `operator>>`, it throws a `std::runtime_error`. This might happen, for instance, if a field is missing, or non-numeric characters are encountered when a number was expected.

The test program below simply copies the file onto the screen. This is the data file I used for testing.

```
999 26380 Houma-Thibodaux, LA  42   42   0   0  0   0   94
288 26420 Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land,
  TX              4424    3046       4       0    1374      34     100
170 26580 Huntington-Ashland, WV-KY-OH  7   1   0   6   0    0     85
```

And this is the complete test program. It contains the full definition for struct `BLS_Table_3u`. This is the one you should copy.

```cpp
// StackOverflow_77548359_BLS_data_Answer.ixx
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/77548359/22193627

export module main;
import std;

struct BLS_Table_3u
{
    // Copy this struct into your own program.
    // Source: https://www.census.gov/construction/bps/txt/tb3u201501.txt
    int csa;
    int cbsa;
    std::string name;
    int total; 
    int units_1; 
    int units_2;
    int units_3_and_4;
    int units_5_or_more;
    int n_structures_with_5_units_or_more;
    int monthly_coverage_percent;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, BLS_Table_3u const& bls)
    {
        ost << bls.csa
            << ' ' << bls.cbsa
            << ' ' << bls.name
            << ' ' << bls.total
            << ' ' << bls.units_1
            << ' ' << bls.units_2
            << ' ' << bls.units_3_and_4
            << ' ' << bls.units_5_or_more
            << ' ' << bls.n_structures_with_5_units_or_more
            << ' ' << bls.monthly_coverage_percent
            << '\n';
        return ost;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ist, BLS_Table_3u& bls)
    {
        if (!(ist >> bls.csa))
        {
            if (ist.eof())
                return ist;
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "BLS_Table_3u: Stream failed mid-record in `operator>>`");
        }
        ist >> bls.cbsa >> std::ws;
        std::string city, state;
        std::getline(ist, city, ',');
        ist >> state 
            >> bls.total 
            >> bls.units_1 
            >> bls.units_2 
            >> bls.units_3_and_4 
            >> bls.units_5_or_more 
            >> bls.n_structures_with_5_units_or_more 
            >> bls.monthly_coverage_percent;
        if (!ist.eof())
            ist.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (ist.fail())
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "BLS_Table_3u: Stream failed mid-record in `operator>>`");
        bls.name = city + ", " + state;
        return ist;
    }
};

export int main()
{
    std::string file_name{ "BLS_Table_3u.txt" };
    std::ifstream ist(file_name);
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error - Could not open data file.\n\n";
        return 1;
    }
    BLS_Table_3u bls;
    while (ist >> bls)
    {
        // After reading a record, you can access its fields 
        // using things like `bls.name` and `bls.total`.
        // For example:
        // 
        //     if (bls.total > 1000) 
        //     {
        //          std::cout << bls.name << " has " 
        //              << bls.total << " units.\n";
        //     }
        // 
        // You can refer to the entire record using `bls` by itself, 
        // which is done below.

        std::cout << bls;  // Write a record to `std::cout`.
    }
    ist.close();
    return 0;
}
// end file: StackOverflow_77548359_BLS_data_Answer.ixx
```

Output:

```
999 26380 Houma-Thibodaux, LA 42 42 0 0 0 0 94
288 26420 Houston-The Woodlands-Sugar Land, TX 4424 3046 4 0 1374 34 100
170 26580 Huntington-Ashland, WV-KY-OH 7 1 0 6 0 0 85
```

Comment: Thank you. I will now try to understand it :)

Comment: Copy the struct into your program. Function `main` (above) shows how to read records from the file. After reading a record, you can access its fields using the things like `bls.name` and `bls.total`. See the comment in function `main`.

Comment: @matheconcs - I updated my answer today, adding what I hope are improved instructions for the stream operators it presents.

Answer (score 0):

What is the key as to when the line is continued? The usual way of handling this is to read successive lines until you hit a non-continued line. If the key is that a continuation line starts with a white space, although the first line never will, using something like the following to read the lines should work:

```
std::string
get_bls_line(
    std::istream&       source )
{
    std::string         result;
    std::getline( source, result );
    while ( std::isspace( source.peek() ) ) {
        std::string         next;
        std::getline( source, next );
        result += next;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then you just parse the lines as if there were no continuation lines. (I wouldn't use `getline` for the parsing. Something with regex would seem more appropriate.)